# Protractor : Reading a json. "Error - Failed: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type function"

Tags: json, protractor

I am trying to read a json file. But I got an error.

Basically there are 2 files - one is the readjson.js (the json reader module) and the other is the protractor file itself

readjson.js file

============================================

```
var jsonreader = function () {


this.parseJSON = function (filename){

    let rawdata = fs.readFile (filename, 'utf8', function (err,contents){

        let data = JSON.parse(contents);
        return (data);
    })

};

};

module.exports = jsonreader;
```

==================================

Protractor spec.js file

=======================================================

```
let jsonreader = require ('./readjson.js');

var readjson = new jsonreader();


describe ('Protractor test json', function (){


browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;


it ("reading json ", () =>{
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);
    var filename = 'user.json';


    readjson.parseJSON(filename,  function (data) {

        console.log ("value is " + data)
    });

})
})
```

===================================================

When I run it , the error "Error - Failed: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type function" appears at this line 
"console.log ("value is " + data)"

I am not able to parse the json file. What did I do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You can directly require json files using `const jsonData = require('./readjson.js');` no need to use the fs module for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution.

Basically I assign a global variable to the data.

```
var data = readmodule.parseJSON (filename)
```

and then if I want to use it

```
data.then (function(userdata){

   console.log (userdata.name)
});
```